# Image Files only accepting .bmp Issue

Tags: vba

When I programmed my code to make the user upload a picture, I tried to code it to get all image files, but it seems to only accept `.bmp` files. So how can I code this for the sheet to accept all file types `(.png, .jpg, .bmp, etc.)`?

```
imagefileformat = "Image Files (*.bmp),others, png (*.png), *.png, tif (*.tif),*.tif, jpg (*.jpg),*.jpg, All Files (*.*),*.*"
myPictureName = Application.GetOpenFilename(imagefileformat)
```

Comment: That is `others`?

Comment: I just started to learn how to code, but do you mean that `others` should be deleted?

Comment: If you managed to compose the rest of the filter string according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.getopenfilename#remarks), that should not come as a surprise? What did you want to achieve by putting it there?

Comment: That was the only thing that actually made my code work, if I omit it, there would be a run-time error. How would I fix it?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/vba/comments/p65tq5/image_files_only_accepting_bmp_issue/h9av4qw?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Answer (score 1):

Syntax is critical (and weird in this case, IYAM). Try

```
imagefileformat = "Image Files (*.bmp; *.png; *.tif; *.jpg),*.bmp;*.png;*.tif;*.jpg"
```

https://www.reddit.com/r/vba/comments/p65tq5/image_files_only_accepting_bmp_issue/h9av4qw/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3